# Google Oauth redirect_uri_mismatch

Tags: google-oauth, next-auth

I am using nextauth for authentication but ever since I went out of testing mode I am getting the following error :
`Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch

You can't sign in to this app because it doesn't comply with Google's OAuth 2.0 policy.

If you're the app developer, register the redirect URI in the Google Cloud Console.
Request details: redirect_uri=https://poempt.vercel.app/api/auth/callback/google
Related developer documentation
`

[I tried adding the uri to the list but it was already there and it warned me about duplicates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hRkt3.png)
Is there anything I can do to fix this ? Github authentication works just fine. The two similar posts suggested as possible duplicates don't help.
Someone request I share the code, but I'm not really sure what to show since I used nextauth so here is the snippet from my loginmodal that deals with google login :

```
import { signIn, useSession } from 'next-auth/react';
const logIn = (provider: string, email = undefined) => {
  email ? signIn(provider, {}, email) : signIn(provider, {});
};

<GoogleLoginButton
            style={style}
            onClick={() => {
              logIn('google');
            }}
          >
            <span>Sign in with Google</span>
          </GoogleLoginButton>
```

Answer (score 1):

I seem to have found the problem. When going into production I forgot to change the environment variables and Vercel still had the old ones with the localhost. I have no idea why the error didn't show me the supposed redirect uri with the localhost domain but at least I found the issue.

If anyone else runs into problems like this, I would suggest copy pasting credentials again just in case you forgot to change them.